# Achieving emailing between website users without "Mailing Server" configuring?

Tags: django, email

I have requirement like, each user of the site
will be mailing any other user and I have rules for that communication
(let them aside for now). So user1 will be picking an email id like:
mypickeduser1n...@sitedomain.com and will be sending an email to
user2, whose email id will be like:
mypickeduser2n...@sitedomain.com. Like that any number of users will
be sending emails to any numbers of users. And any outsider should be
able to send an email to mypickeduser2n...@sitedomain.com. My question
is,So in this context, do I need to build my own smtp(setup mailing)
servers. I am totally a newbie in the smtp arena. Can I achieve the
email communication between the users without "mailing server"
configurations?
Can this be achievable?

Comment: Ambiguity: you list mail from outside as a requirement, but then ask if internal mail is possible without a mail server. Please specify more clearly whether it's an internal+external or internal-only setup.

Answer (score 4):

You need a mail server.  Even if local email is just directly deposited into a mail directory or database somewhere, something has to be responsible for accepting email from the outside world.  I recommend postfix - it's powerful but easy to set up, and the config files don't look like Klingon.

Answer (score 2):

If you want users to be able to create e-mail accounts in [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), you need Django, your [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transfer_agent) and your [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP)/POP server to use the same user account database.

I've successfully used the following setup:

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) as the user database
- [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) as the MTA
- [Dovecot](http://www.postfix.org/) as the IMAP server
- a custom Django app as the user account management front-end
- virtual mail user accounts (not using Unix accounts)

I've only used the Django admin interface to let administrators manage the mail accounts, but a management UI for users is trivial to implement as well.

Some tips and sources of information for such a setup:

- Design your database schema carefully. I based mine on howtos mentioned below with modifications for easier Django integration.
- Take care that all components use the same encryption for user passwords.
- two howtos ([first](http://www.lxtreme.nl/index.pl/docs/linux/dovecot_postfix_pam), [second](http://www.gjdv.at/snippets/linux/virtual_mail_hosting)) describing how Dovecot and Postfix can authenticate users using PAM and PostgreSQL as backend
- a [howto in German](http://www.tuxj0b.de/HOWTO_Mailserver_mit_Postfix_Dovecot_Antispam_und_PostgreSQL_Backend) for Dovecot/Postfix/PostgreSQL
- a [howto](http://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/DovecotPostgresql) for gluing together virtual user/domain support for Debian, Postfix 2 with SMTP AUTH, SASL2 with libpam-pgsql for Postfix, PostgreSQL and Dovecot
- the [Postfix PostgreSQL howto](http://www.postfix.org/PGSQL_README.html)

You might also want to check out the [Virtual Mail Manager](http://vmm.localdomain.org/) command line tool for managing domains, accounts and aliases with a Dovecot/Postfix/PostgreSQL setup.

Comment: How do you tie up Django and Postfix(or any other MTA such as sendmail) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few django apps out there to handle messaging between users, but the only one that seems to be active is:

[django-messages](http://code.google.com/p/django-messages/)

This gives you all the functionality you asked for, except for outsiders being able to send mail in to users.

This is a much harder problem and will certainly require a mail server and much custom code on your part.